# Swapping a stringstream for cout

Tags: c++, iostream

With glibc's stdio, I can swap a memstream for stdout, thereby capturing the output of a piece of code compiled to output to stdout:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swapfiles(FILE* f0, FILE* f1){ FILE tmp; tmp = *f0; *f0 = *f1; *f1 = tmp; }

void hw_c(){ puts("hello c world"); }

int c_capt(){
  FILE* my_memstream;
  char* buf  = NULL;
  size_t bufsiz = 0;

  if( (my_memstream = open_memstream(&buf, &bufsiz)) == NULL) return 1;

  FILE * oldstdout = stdout;

  swapfiles(stdout, my_memstream);
  hw_c();
  swapfiles(stdout, my_memstream);

  fclose(my_memstream);
  printf("Captured: %s\n", buf);
}
```

I'm curious if the same is possible for `iostreams`.
My naive attempt won't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void hw_cc(){ std::cout<<"hello c++ world\n"; }
int cc_capt(){
  using namespace std;

  stringstream ss;
  string capt;

  //std::swap(ss,cout); //<- the compiler doesn't like this
  hw_cc();
  //std::swap(ss,cout); 

  cout<<"Captured: "<<capt<<'\n';
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  c_capt();
  puts("---------------------------------");
  cc_capt();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't spam tags! C is a different language!

Comment: `std::cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf())`, but realistically you'd define `int cc_capt(std::ostream&)` and pass the stream in.

Comment: @user657267, if you do not have access to all the functions (such as `cc_hw()`) then capturing the `std::cout` is a pretty good way. I do that in some of my unit tests where certain functions just print messages in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but you don't swap the whole stream--just the stream buffer.

```
void cc_capt() {
    using namespace std;

    stringstream ss;

    auto orig = std::cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());

    hw_cc();

    std::cout.rdbuf(orig);

    std::cout << "captured: " << ss.str() << "\n";
}
```

Note that in this case, we're not really using the `stringstream` itself at all, just the `stringbuf` it contains. If we wanted, we could just define a `basic_stringbuf<char>` and use that directly instead of defining a `stringstream` and then only use the `stringbuf` it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jerry's samples, I wrote a template which has one great advantage, it's *safe* (i.e. if an exception occurs, your buffer gets restored automatically.)

Use this way:

```
{
  ostream_to_buf<char> buf(std::cout);

  ... run code which `std::cout << "data"` ...

  std::string const output(buf.str());

  ... do something with `output` ...
}  // <-- here the buffer is restored
```

Here is the functional template which I think follows the STL pretty closely. The template is itself an `std::stringbuf` which inserts itself in the constructor. The destructor restores the original buffer so it is exception safe.

```
template<
      class CharT
    , class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>
    , class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
>
class ostream_to_buf
    : public std::basic_stringbuf<CharT, Traits, Allocator>
{
public:
    typedef CharT                       char_type;
    typedef Traits                      traits_type;
    typedef typename Traits::int_type   int_type;
    typedef typename Traits::pos_type   pos_type;
    typedef typename Traits::off_type   off_type;
    typedef Allocator                   allocator_type;

    typedef std::basic_stringbuf<char_type, traits_type, allocator_type>    stringbuf_type;
    typedef std::basic_ostream<char_type, traits_type>                      stream_type;
    typedef std::basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type>                    streambuf_type;
    typedef std::basic_string<char_type, traits_type, allocator_type>       string_type;

    ostream_to_buf<char_type, traits_type, allocator_type>(stream_type & out)
        : f_stream(out)
        , f_original(f_stream.rdbuf(this))
    {
    }

    ostream_to_buf<char_type, traits_type, allocator_type>(ostream_to_buf<char_type, traits_type, allocator_type> const & rhs) = delete;
    ostream_to_buf<char_type, traits_type, allocator_type> & operator = (ostream_to_buf<char_type, traits_type, allocator_type> const & rhs) = delete;

    ~ostream_to_buf()
    {
        f_stream.rdbuf(f_original);
    }

private:
    stream_type &       f_stream;
    streambuf_type *    f_original = nullptr;
};
```

The copy constructor and assignment operator are deleted because these do not work in this case.

You probably can make it work with C++11 or even C++03. I have C++14 but I don't think any of these require C++14.